# Selenium IDE - Find link within the same row of a specific text from table

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I have a specific table that is within multiple tables, and does not have any unique ID or Name. I'm looking for a dynamic solution to find a specific text that will surely occur only once in the whole document, and get the WebElement of the link (text = Add) within the same row.

The text i'm looking for is in the 1st column, and the link is in the 6th column.

Basically i'm looking for a selenium alternate of nextSibling() with a twist that it has to be a link.

Comment: A solution is to store the whole table in an array, and iterate through... but i'm sure there is a simpler, less resource-wasting method.

Answer (score 3):

selenium supports XPATH which has the notions of siblings and first children etc. You can iterate but this approach makes it more robust. You can select  elements too.

Comment: XPATH is working fine as long as there are no upper or lowercase differences... is there any way to counter it? i have tried `*//td[contains(translate(.,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLOMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),'text')]/../td/a` but this way it won't find it

Answer (score 0):

selenium IDE supports `XPATH` for finding the value or location uniquely in web page and it show notions of siblings and first children etc.

you can used Xpath of that value to find it.